# I am getting an error after changing the applicationId on my build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

```
 def localProperties = new **Properties()**
 def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
 if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
     localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
     }
 }

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new **FileNotFoundException**("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

I am getting an error of Properties() class and FileNotFoundException. I got this error after trying to change my application Id. how can I solve this issue.

Comment: the ** on the Properties() class is not part of the code, I just put there to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `local.properties` file under the android folder.